Why is stepper motor closed loop vs open loop control such a drastic difference?
(Please move this to Electrical Engineering SE if appropriate)
Good day. I've been trying to build an inverted pendulum on a cart Linear Quadratic Regulator controller after teaching myself the math behind it. I have a set of coupled second order nonlinear ordinary differential equations for how this thing moves, and I've linearized around the up-position fixed point.
That context isn't terribly important. The thing is, I've gone with using stepper motors rather than DC motors, like I should have since the start, since my control input is force, mathematically.
My workaround in my implementation has been to compute what "force" I must apply every time I take my measurements, and computing $\ddot x$, numerically updating a target $\dot x$ every cycle to update my stepper's constant velocity so fast that I effectively get an acceleration effect.
Here's my problem: I used a BIGTREETECH S42C V1.1 closed loop stepper motor controller at first, which is typically used for 3D printers actually, but has the exact same breakout pinout as an A4988 stepper driver, and it worked absolutely beautifully and held the rod perfectly straight. Unfortunately, however, from one day to the next, it simply refused to turn on anymore, and I'm on a deadline. I had to scavenge some garbage to get an open-loop TB6600 and another stepper. I ran the exact same code with this new setup, after reconfiguring step counts and such, but now it runs absolutely HORRIBLY. It's extremely twitchy and just flings itself all over the place. I refuse to believe closed-loop vs open-loop has made such a ridiculous difference. I'm making sure to set the TB6600 to a good maximum current too, and the stepper isn't stalling, but it just behaves horribly unstable. Are there other reasons this could be the case?
